# Android, perform action when widget is clicked

Tags: android, widget, android-intent

Can someone provide me with an example of how to perform an action when the user taps on a widget? The only example I have found launches an activity. I assume that it must still do it with some sort of pending intent and maybe a broadcast receiver, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent` on the views in your widget (assuming you have views in your widget).

Comment: Do you have some example code? I've tried something like this but could not get it to work. I tried to create a pending intent for a broadcast receiver but it seemed like the intent was never received.

Comment: What kind of action are you trying to trigger?

Comment: Any kind basically. One of my plans is to acquire an image from the camera. Like this app I downloaded the other day, it just turns on the cameras flash led so it works like a flashlight.

Comment: Do you have a specific example? Can you post the code where you set up the PendingIntent?

Comment: Yes, I just posted it as a new question. I asked this question first because I didn't know if I was even headed the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329440/android-widget-click-and-broadcast-receiver-not-working